# Xamarin Android Share Link/Text via social media from custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I wan't to share a link via social media from custom renderer

```
public class CustomActions : ICustomActions
    {
        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        public void ShareThisLink()
        {
            Intent sharingInt = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
            sharingInt.SetType("text/plain");
            string shareBody = "https://www.google.com";
            sharingInt.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subject");
            sharingInt.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, shareBody);
            context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingInt, "Share via"));
        }

    }
```

This error occur

```
Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

even when I added the below code I still get same error

```
 sharingInt.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `Intent.CreateChooser` creates yet another `Intent`. What you want to do is to set the flag on this new intent:

```cs
public void ShareThisLink()
{
    Intent sharingInt = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
    sharingInt.SetType("text/plain");
    string shareBody = "https://www.google.com";
    sharingInt.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subject");
    sharingInt.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, shareBody);
    var intent = Intent.CreateChooser(sharingInt, "Share via");
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Alternatively to avoid the need to do this, you could cache the `MainActivity` instance Xamarin.Forms uses:

```
public MainActivity
{
   public static MainActivity Instance {get;private set;}

   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       Instance = this;
       ...
   }
}
```

And then use the `Instance` as the `Context` in your code instead of the `Application.Context`

Comment: WOW!  Not only did you provide a solution to my issue, you provided TWO.  Both worked, and that context issue has been a big issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: @bobwki Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!